# DNS subdomain problem

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain

I am developing an application where every user has a subdomain

`xyz.alumclub.net`

where the `xyz` will take him to his subdomain.

For the above alumclub.net, I am trying to set up the blog at blog.alumclub.net.

1. I have created another A record:

   `blog.alumclub.net A 192.168.0.100`
2. But the above is not coming into effect because of the rule

   `*.alumclub.net -> 192.168.0.200`

Because of rule 2, blog.domainname.com is not going to my blog hosted on posterous (http://alumclub.posterous.com/) instead it is going to my server and treating the blog as subdomain of user.

How can I solve this problem? Is it possible to solve?

Comment: Please rewrite your question with real names and addresses.  Reading all these hypothetical addresses makes my head hurt.

Comment: Sure will do that.One more thing is as a new user it is not allowing me to post more than one link.

Comment: I tried to find a question in this I could answer, but I failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As womble and Michael Graff wrote, your question is extremely confused. I cannot parse it entirely but I can try to point some issues:

1. Is the domain alumclub.NET or alumclub.COM ? You used both and it is hard to know if it is significant.
2. DNS wildcards do **not** have precedence over ordinary names so, unlike what you wrote, `*.alumclub.net` does **not** block `blog.alumclub.net`

So, there is no reason it should not work. Try it, and, if it fails, post **details**: **real** domain names, actual config, actual error messages, not vague summaries.

Comment: iam sorry for that. But i understood your answer clearly let me tryout your solution and will come back with great clarity if it does not work

Comment: Thanks i resolved.Somehow previously i observed the above problem :( :( .